# Android Market Server

Tags: android, web-services, google-play

What kind of technique does the Android Market Server use to build their server?
I mean, like PHP, Ruby on rail? or something else?

Or it is just a web server like some web site and base on the HTTP protocol?

Why internet browser can not connect to the Android Market Server?

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of technique does the Android Market Server use to build their server? I mean, like PHP, Ruby on rail? or something else?

That is not public information, sorry.

> Or it is just a web server like some web site and base on the HTTP protocol?

Well, yes, most Web servers are based on the HTTP protocol.

> Why internet browser can not connect to the Android Market Server?

http://market.android.com works quite nicely for most people.